# How do I Eas build into an expo organization instead of my personal expo account?

Tags: expo

my boss has recently made an expo organization so we can start working together more on our builds. He invited me to the organization, and I accepted, however, I am confused about how I build to this organization instead of my personal account? Whenever I try to upload a new build with

```
eas build --profile preview --platform android
```

It continues to build in my personal expo account instead of adding it to the organization account as well. My boss made sure to give me all the privileges so I know that is not the issue. I have also tried logging out eas and logging back into eas using 'eas logout/login'. For such a simple question, I have had a hard time finding a quick solution to this. If anyone has insight on this, that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: also wanted to add that I have looked around a decent amount and have checked the [accounts expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/accounts/account-types/), and they don't mention how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

In project's root, you have app.json file, add the following:

```
"owner": "<yourOrganization>"
```

Once you do it, run:

```
eas build:configure
```

It will fetch the correct project under your given organization.

Answer (score 2):

Did you transfer the app you are building to the organization in expo website (Settings / Transfer Project)?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to (re)initialize the project to the organization ID. Try:

`eas init --id=XXXXX`

where XXXXX is the correct project ID (in the organization). Then do your build command.

See: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli#eas-init

Answer (score 0):

You can log out of your personal account and log in with your organization's credentials if you'd rather use your organization's account instead of your own.

```
eas logout

eas login
```

see: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli#eas-logout